# PHP referrer domain and subfile

Tags: php, referrer

I have this code:

```
$allowed_host = 'domain.com';
$host = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST);

if(substr($host, 0 - strlen($allowed_host)) == $allowed_host) {
  echo "ok";
} else {
  echo "not ok";
  exit();
}
```

This code based on domain but how can I check domain and php file?

```
If referrer page: domain.com/fromok.php {echo "ok";} else {echo "not ok";}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will give you 'ok' if the request host name ends with `'domian.com'`, for example if it is `'adomian.com'`. I assume you don't want it.

You can use

```
$allowed_host = 'domain.com';
$allowed_path = '/fromok.php';
$url_components = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

if((($url_components['host'] === $allowed_host) || (substr($url_components['host'], - (strlen($allowed_host) + 1) === '.' . $allowed_host)) && ($url_components['path'] === $allowed_path)) {
  echo "ok";
} else {
  echo "not ok";
  exit();
}
```